# Android Java Voice Recognition only need 1 result.......How to obtain 1 result?

Tags: java, android

I have a speech recognition program that displays 5-6 results. I only want the 1st result to appear. Can you help with this please?

code:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    if (requestCode == check && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        ArrayList<String> results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));

    }
```

Please advise?

Thank you.
FlinxSYS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a flag called [`RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html#EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS). You have to do this before the `startActivityForResult`-call I guess (from [the voice recognition example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/VoiceRecognition.html)):

```
// Specify how many results you want to receive. The results will be sorted
// where the first result is the one with higher confidence.
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1);

// ...
startActivityForResult(intent,0);
```

Comment: Nice job, thanks. How can I set the 1 result to a variable to utilize in an IF THEN statement ?

Comment: You mean the result in `onActivityResult`? Well you can read out the first string with: `String voiceResult = results.get(0);` (see [ArrayList.get](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get%28int%29) for more Info). If you want to get the string out of your `ListView` you could try that: `String voiceResult = lv.getAdapter().getItem(0).toString();`.

Comment: Does this go in the mainfest? I put it in the activity undr piblic class with other variables/strings and it did not error when I used the second suggestion. If could not define 'results' on the first option, fyi. Thank you! Again! So now this should work: if (voiceResult.equals("google")){ command here } how would I open default browser to specified URL?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a flag indicating that a result was already found:

```
private boolean flag = false;

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    if (!flag && requestCode == check && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        ArrayList<String> results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));
        flag = true;
    }
```

Once the flag is set to true at the first found result, the if condition will be false for any other execution of the handler.

Comment: What is the string to use in the IF THEN statement? (ie: the 1 result)

Comment: String result = RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS;   ??